# Keyboard shortcut to focus on (idle) terminal

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I would like to know, if there is possible to use keyboard shortcut to focus on first **idle** (non working) terminal window in unity (13.10)? Something like <kbd>Ctr</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, but before opening the new instance of terminal, searching for any **idle** instance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First set the world "Terminal" to appear in the window title of your gnome-terminal. To do this, when you are in gnome-terminal go to **Edit** → **Profile Preferences**, select **Title and Command** tab and be sure that the field **Initial title** contain the word "Terminal":

[image: Terminal - Title and Command]

Second, add a new custom keyboard shortcut for the following command:

```
bash -c "[[ \"$(cat /proc/$(xdotool getwindowpid $(xdotool getwindowfocus))/comm)\" != \"gnome-terminal\" ]] && wmctrl -a Terminal || xdotool key Alt+grave"
```

To do this, go to **System Settings** → **Keyboard**, **Shortcuts** tab, select **Custom Shortcut** and add a new custom shortcut:

[image: Add custom shortcut]

As you can see, I chose as shortcut <kbd>F8</kbd> key which is working great in this case for me.

**Note**: `wmctrl` and `xdotool` must to be installed in order to use them. If you don't have them installed, you can install them from terminal using:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
```

Comment: For downvoters: please leave a comment - I can improve the answer only if I can know the reason of downvoting.

Comment: What is a purpose of "xdotool key Alt+grave" ?  (i've tried your solution, actually it happens noting)

Comment: @ts01 Alt+` should switch to another instance of terminal if you have more than one opened and if the focus is on one of them. What keys did you used for the custom shortcut? F8 like I said in the answer?

Comment: Yes. It didn't work, but +25 for efforts, anyway

Comment: I am still using it from when I gave you this answer. So you should review all the steps, maybe you made something wrong.